# Running UserData with Powershell >= 7.0 on Windows Server 2022 on EC2

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2022, ec2-userdata

UserData by default will run with Powershell V5.1 on the Windows Server 2022 AMI on an AWS EC2 instance that spins up. However, I want to use some cmdlets that are only supported in Powershell version 7 and greater.

How am I best able to run a script with Powershell 7+ when booting the instance with UserData?

I currently have a script that installs powershell 7, but then from that point I am not sure how to use v7 to run the rest of the commands that I have.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.3.1/PowerShell-7.3.1-win-x64.msi -OutFile PowerShell.msi
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i PowerShell.msi /quiet' -Wait
```

I am using the WINDOWS_SERVER_2022_ENGLISH_FULL_BASE AMI.

I have tried using something like `Invoke-Expression`, and also have tried to get the script to call itself recursively with some conditionals, e.g.

```
# First Run with ps 5.1
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt [Version]"7.0") {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.3.1/PowerShell-7.3.1-win-x64.msi -OutFile PowerShell.msi
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i PowerShell.msi /quiet' -Wait
    cd "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7"
    # Run this same script with ps7
    ./pwsh $PSCommandPath
    exit
}

# 
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -gt [Version]"7.0") {
    # Do the things I need to do with ps7...
}
```

Both of my attempts have been silently failing, and with ec2 userdata it is very hard to get info on why.

Comment: how about placing the code you want to run inside a scriptblock (`{...}`), call it using the invocation operator (`&`), then do the same with PowerShell 7 by calling the application itself, or entering into pwsh as an interactive console.

Comment: Would you be able to give a short example of the scriptblock and invocation operator? I don't think that I would be able to enter into pwsh interactively, as it all needs to be done via script, and there won't be any human intervention.

Comment: Sure. Like this: `$scriptblock = {Param($text)Write-Host -Object "$text " -NoNewline;};& $scriptblock 'Hello';pwsh.exe -Command "$scriptblock 'World'"`

Comment: @Michael - is there anything useful in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log? Have you tried putting some print statements etc to see where it is failing by any chance?
What exactly is your UserData? Is it even running PowerShell code within<PowerShell>.. </PowerShell> ?

Comment: @AdilHindistan, this is a Windows Instance so the logs are found here:
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2Launch\log\agent.log
What I'm finding is that when something has gone wrong, usually I can't even connect to the instance via SSM. I'm using CDK and the UserData class, so my script gets wrapped correctly in the `<powershell>` tags. I know my UserData script is getting in there because I can find it in on the instance once I do have a connection.

Comment: Use two scripts, one to install powershell and the other to run your code?

Comment: @Michael - of course you're right about location. Honestly, your script looks fine. It might  be worth looking into separating the PS7 code to a different script like Paolo suggested . You can include commands to download and run the script from s3. You need a way to get logs which means you need a functioning instance first, run the pwsh code second. Once you figure out the problem, you can put it back again.

Comment: @AdilHindistan Thanks! This idea of downloading the second script from S3 and executing it via the initial UserData turned out to be a bit easier and more ergonomic than putting the code inside a script block (which did work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach that ended up working was to have 2 different scripts. The first script installs PS7, and then downloads the second script from S3 and executes it using PS7.

**User Data exectued with PS5:**

```
#init.ps1
<powershell>
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.3.1/PowerShell-7.3.1-win-x64.msi -OutFile PowerShell.msi
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i PowerShell.msi /quiet' -Wait
cd "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7"
mkdir (Split-Path -Path 'C:/temp/setupGateway.ps1' ) -ea 0
Read-S3Object -BucketName 'my-bucket' -key 'setupGateway.ps1' -file 'C:/temp/setupGateway.ps1' -ErrorAction Stop
& "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh" "C:\temp\setupGateway.ps1"
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

**PS7 script, executed separately:**

```
# setup.ps1
Write-Output $PSVersionTable
Write-Output "Hello from PS7"
```

All that needs to happen to make this work is to make sure that you copy the `setup.ps1` script to an S3 location. Which can be achieved in lots of different ways depending on the rest of your setup.